# Deploying my own created (custom) Deep learning Model on AWS SageMaker

Tags: amazon-ec2, deep-learning, computer-vision, amazon-sagemaker

I'm new to AWS SageMaker, and my question may seem silly. I've created a deep learning model that requires GPU and deployed that model on EC2 instances (g4dn.4xlarge
) with Auto Scaling and a load balancer. The application is running well, but I have some questions:

1. Is it best practice to deploy a deep learning model on EC2 with Auto Scaling and a load balancer, or should it be deployed on AWS SageMaker (considering cost)?
2. How can I simply deploy my model on SageMaker and create endpoints? My model is already built, trained, and tested, and I just want to deploy it on AWS SageMaker.
   Your guidance will be highly appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

1. With SageMaker, the price ml instance price premium (ml.g4dn.4xlarge vs g4dn.4xlarge) already includes the Load balancer costs. Also, you deploy through Python code and need to know and do far less devops work. So it depends on the level of knowledge you have and how much control you need. When your workload grows more complex in terms of CI/CD, operations and MLOps than obviously SageMaker has built-in tools to support that.
2. The exact way to deploy depends on several factors you didn't mention like: PyTorch/Tensorflow/other? and which version? do you need realtime inference or async/batch? Do you need your own container, or can get by using an AWS deep learning container?
   Depending on these answers, there are many examples available in [SageMaker examples](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples).
   I suggest you should [get started here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/deploy-model.html) to understand the basic concepts. Then [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/realtime-endpoints-deploy-models.html#deploy-models-python) is a typical deployment via Python.

Comment: thank for explanation and suggestions. basically my model is on Pytorch,CV, CUDA, need async inference and use my own docker container.

Comment: Async walkthrough: https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/async-inference/Async-Inference-Walkthrough-SageMaker-Python-SDK.ipynb
It's easier if you can avoid bringing your own container, and instead install any dependencies when the endpoint initializes (via PIP or whatever). If not then the next best thing it to extend an existing container like in this example, https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/advanced_functionality/pytorch_extend_container_train_deploy_bertopic/BERTtopic_extending_container.ipynb
otherwise find a Bring Your Container Example